# What happens when I pass regular functions(without callback & not a promise) to Promise.join?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm learning Promises and found code at work that basically has a list of function calls in Promise.join. What does this do? I'm assuming that they execute in parallel but is the promise considered automatically resolved when the function returns?

For reference, this is with the bluebird promise library.

Comment: Have you tried...reading the documentation that explains this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Promise.join` you pass it several *promises* and a function to execute when they're all done with all their values.

All the function calls create promises, which are resolved *concurrently* - since the functions have already executed by the time `.join` is called - the operations have already started. Promises are proxies for values - the operations themselves have already executed or are out of your control.

```
Promise.join(somePromise, someOtherPromise, (first, second) => {
  // both here
});
```

Comment: Why does `Promise.join()` exist instead of just using `Promise.all().then()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 it's just a convenience and it is a lot easier to soundly type in typescript.

Comment: so if somePromise is just a function, Promise.join wraps that in a promise?